# Query Active Directory Username from login, to match a Name stored in another database

Tags: sql, asp.net, ldap

I am developing an application in Asp.net using Active Directory to authenticate users. I have been asked to create a timesheet and project management application. The application should allow managers to; select a user,assign a task and show their personal information.

To do this I will need to connect to one of their databases that holds all the relevant data.

What I have done so far is create a modal with a dropdownlist and a connection string to the database needed. The dropdownlist allows you to select a name,a task, task department and task description. I would like it to bind the selected data into a second grid view on their personal profile page.

My problem is that it needs to match the username stored in Active directory when they login, to the name selected from the database in the dropdownlist.

I am lost on how this can be done, I really hope that this makes sense I may have got lost in the woods on this!! I am new to AD.

[Attached Image gives you an idea on the dropdownlist and data to bind to the gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXFf3.png)

Comment: Typically, the samAccountName or userPrincipalName are the unique attributes that you would use to perform a search against in Microsoft Active Directory

Comment: I have tried using a dropdownlist to load active directory usernames to add in to a user store in my application, Its not loading correctly the error displaying is [ System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error (0x80005000)]